# Directory Structure and Import

Tags: go

I do not understand how the package / project directory structure works.
I am following these 2 links [enter link description here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) and [enter link description here](https://medium.com/rungo/everything-you-need-to-know-about-package-in-go-b8bac62b74cc)

My Go workspace is located under /workspace/golang.
My `$GOPATH` is equal to `/workspace/golang`

My directory structure is as follow :

```
/workspace/golang/src/Tutorial/
...tutorial_main.go              <- Default 'Hello World' program
...library/
......arithmetic.go
```

Content of arithmetic.go :

```
package library

func addNum(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
```

I `cd` into library folder and ran `go build arithmetic`

Now, I cannot figure out how to use my arithmetic.go in my tutorial_main.go file.
I tried the following :

```
import "library"
fmt.Println("Result : ", library.addNum(1,4))

import "Tutorial/library"
fmt.Println("Result : ", library.addNum(1,4))

import "src/Tutorial/library"
fmt.Println("Result : ", library.addNum(1,4))
```

Neither works. 
It keep saying it cannot find `library`
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your setup, the package import path is:

```
import "Tutorial/library"
```

And you should capitalize the names you want to export in the library package so you can access them from other packages.

In general, the import path is the file path of the package (relative to $GOPATH) if it is local, or the remote path of the package, such as `github.com/myaccount/package`. The simple import names such as `import library` are reserved for built-in packages. Relative import paths also work, but they are not recommended, i.e. `import ./library`.

That said, with the module system $GOPATH is no longer used. I recommend you read modules and how you can work outside the $GOPATH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Capital letter was the missing link. I will check to remove the GOPATH as you indicated.
Thanks alot for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, your variables and functions that you'd like to export (make available outside your package) need to start with a capital letter.

```
package library

func privateAddNum(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}

func PublicAddNum(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
```

`privateAddNum` is an **unexported** function and will only be accessible within the `library` package.

`PublicAddNum` is an **exported** function and will be accessible to external packages that import `library`.

Comment: Ohhh... there we go. Capital letter. :FacePalm:
I reread both link that I am following and it was, in bold, in the ```medium``` link. Clearly ... reading failure.
I wasted so much time on this. At least, I will never ever forget that.
Thanks alot!